# Single LINQ expression to tally up several columns in a DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `DataSet` with several rows and columns (as DataSets tend to have).  I need to create a tally row on the bottom with sums of each column.  I'd like to do this with a single LINQ expression, as it will simplify a bunch of my code.  I can get the total of a single column like so:

```
var a = (from m in month
         where <some long expression>
         select m["BGCO_MINUTES"] as Decimal?).Sum();
```

However, I want totals for other columns as well.  I don't want to use multiple LINQ expressions because there's also a complicated *where* clause in there, and I'm doing several tally rows with various expressions and only want to loop through this set once.  I also don't want to manually loop through the dataset myself and add up the totals since I'm creating many of these tally rows and think it would be messier.

What I want is an anonymous type that contains a total of `BGCO_MINUTES`, `800IB_MINUTES` and `TSDATA_MINUTES`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// run the filters once and get List<DataRow> with the matching rows
var list = (from m in month
            where <some long expression>
            select m).ToList();

// build the summary object
var result = new {
    BGCO_MINUTES = list.Sum(m => m["BGCO_MINUTES"] as Decimal?),
    _800IB_MINUTES= list.Sum(m => m["800IB_MINUTES"] as Decimal?),
}
```

And that's assuming your where clause is not just long to type, but computationally expensive to evaluate.  That *will* iterate through the list once per column.

If you really want to only iterate the list once, you can probably do it with [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218), but the code is less elegant (in my opinion):

```
// run the filters once and get List<DataRow> with the matching rows
var a = (from m in month
         where <some long expression>
         select m)
        .Aggregate(           new { BGCO_MINUTES  = (decimal?)0m,
                                   _800IB_MINUTES = (decimal?)0m },
                    (ac,v) => new { BGCO_MINUTES  = ac.BGCO_MINUTES + (decimal?)v["BGCO_MINUTES"],
                                  _800IB_MINUTES = ac._800IB_MINUTES + (decimal?)v["800IB_MINUTES"] });
```

Like I said, I think it's less elegant than the first version, but it should work.  Even though the first one requires a temporary copy of the values that match the where clause (memory cost) and 1 pass through the list for each field (CPU cost), I think it's a lot more readable than the latter version - make sure the performance difference is worth it before using the less-understandable version.

Comment: Hmm.. apparently SO doesn't give you a little popup thingy when someone else posts a response while you're writing (or else I missed it).  Oh well.  My point about readability (and the performance difference likely being small unless there's a massive amount of data involved) still stands.

Comment: +1. Yes, simple Sum are more readable. +your sample does not have extra classes and uses OP's objects.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure this is the approach I will be taking.  I started with the approach @AlexeiLevenkov posted and it quickly started getting very messy :)  The data won't be large enough for any perf concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218) instead of Sum as it is more flexible - you will be able to have object (or simply dictionary) to hold sums for individual columns while iterating through each row.

(non-compiled code ahead)

```
class SumObject { 
  public float First; 
  public float Second; 
}

var filtered = (from m in month
     where <some long expression>
     select m;

filtered.Aggregate(new SumObject(), (currentSum, item)=> { 
  currentSum.First += item.First;  
  currentSum.Second += item.Second;
  return currentSum;
});
```